# Under what conditions does the two-sided DKW inequality become a strict equality?

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

If the two-sided DKW inequality is tight, then there should be a choice of distribution and sample size where the equality holds. What is it?